# initial connection request is not finished yet

Tags: laravel, http

С компьютера клиента на сайт при отправке некоторых данных на сервер через форму (с загрузкой изображений и pdf), запрос не отправляется, в network во вкладке timing пишет "initial connection request is not finished yet" и просто висит запрос с обработке. Происходит так только на компьютере у клиента в офисе. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать. Сайт на Laravel.